# Textbox to array declaration in C# windows form

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi I’m fairly new to c# programming so please bear with me. I’m currently working on a “simple” little program which allows the user to enter 25 values into the same text box and once this has been done I want to be able to display this 25 values in a list box as an array of 5 row by 5 column and I want to find out the largest number in the array.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int arrayrows = 5;
    int arraycolomns = 5;
    int[,] arraytimes;
    arraytimes = new int[array rows, array columns];

    // list_Matrix.Items.Add(tb_First.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != 5; j++)
        {
            array times [i,j]= Convert. To Int32(Tb_First.Text);
            list_Matrix.Items.Add(array times[i, j].To String());
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried for displaying the array in a list box, but it isn't working. This also prevents me from moving to the next section of finding the largest number among them.

Comment: Instead of posting new question every time on exactly the same topic, please **improve your first question** and add more details in there

Comment: If you want 5 rows by 5 column why `int arrayrows = 2;
            int arraycolomns = 2;`

Comment: Have you tried using string.Split method (although it would give you a one dimensional array) to split your textBox.Text and then add those values into the listBox?

Comment: no i haven't tried tat method..

Comment: totally agreed with @ShadowWizard. U r asking too many questions on same topic.

Comment: but am not getting an answer.. people are busy commenting and criticizing.. none has come out with a solution..

Comment: How do you split the values? What is the value delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using .Split(' ') (or any other character or string). This will give you a onedimensional array with 25 elements (if everything was entered). The trick to converting that into a twodimensional array or grid is to use integer division and modulo, the following code would to

```
String[] splitText = textBox.Text.Split(' '); //gets your 25-length 1D array

//make an empty grid with the right dimensions first
int[][] grid = new int[5][];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    grid[i] = new int[5];
}

//save our highest value
int maxVal = 0;
//then fill this grid
for (int i=0;i<splitText.Length;i++){
    int value = int.Parse(splitText[i]);
    //i%5 gives us values from 0 to 4, which is our 'x-coordinate' in the grid
    //i/5 uses integer division so its the same as Math.floor(i/5.0), giving us your 'y-coordinates'
    grid[i%5][i/5] = value;

    //check if this value is larger than the one that is currently the largest
    if (value > maxVal)
    {
        maxVal = value;
    }       
}
```

This will fill the twodimensional grid array with the split textbox text, and if there are not enough values in the textbox it leaves a 0 in those cells.

At the end you will also have your maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (shows by printing the numbers as string). and assuming you enter the numbers in the following way,

'1,2,3,4...'

```
string[] nums=txtBox.Text.Split(',');
lstBox.Items.Clear();
int colCount=5;
int colIndex=0;
string line="";
foreach(string num in nums)
{
   if(colIndex==colCount)
   {
     lstBox.Items.Add(line);
     line="";
     colIndex=0;
   }
   line+= line==""? num : " "+num;
   colIndex+=1;
}
if(line!="")
   lstBox.Items.Add(line);
```

Make sure to correct any syntax mistakes, and to change the parameter names to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] ab=new int[10];
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            int j = 0;


            string [] a = (s.Split(' '));
            foreach (string  word in a)
            {
                ab[j] = Convert.ToInt32(word);
                j++;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                label2.Text +=ab[i].ToString()+" ";
            }
        }
```